Why do the sounds of suffering in song give us pleasure?
If you listen to the radio, many of the songs have singers with a distressed voice. Why do we get pleasure from hearing songs like this? Are there any studies on this topic?

Welcome J.Doe. Please take our [tour] and refer to the [ask] section of the [help]. You'll find we require evidence of your prior research into the topic, that you show what you searched, found and where you got stuck. Please [edit] to add those. If you're stuck finding any, try the search terms "music psychology affect" (yes, that's affect with an "a").
